# Change FormBuilder array items in nested forms

Tags: javascript, angular, angular2-forms

According to the API documentation the proper way to change nested values is to use method `patchValue`

`myForm.patchValue({'key': {'subKey': 'newValue'}});`

But how to change values in nested arrays like **list** of cars in this example below. How to get first item of **list** array an change `model` to `Fiesta`? [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/K6VB3O?p=preview)

`myForm.patchValue({'list': 0: {'model': 'Fiesta'});` is not working.

```
@Component({
  moduleId: __moduleName,
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `<div><pre>{{ myForm.value | json }}</pre></div>`
})
export class AppComponent {

  public myForm: FormGroup;

  constructor(@Inject(FormBuilder) private _fb: FormBuilder) {

    this.myForm = this._fb.group({
      name: 'Cars',
      list:  this._fb.array([
        this.initCar(),
        this.initCar(),
        this.initCar()
      ]),
    });
    /** Change value Here **/
    this.myForm.patchValue({name: 'Automobile'});
  };

  initCar() {
    return this._fb.group({
      automaker: 'Ford',
      model:     'Fusion'
    });
  }
}
```

[Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/K6VB3O?p=preview)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I did something similar not that long ago just add.

```
const patchV = (<FormArray>this.myForm.controls['list']).at(0) as FormArray;
patchV.patchValue({automaker: 'CoolCar', model: 'Bucket'})
```

Working Example [plunker]http://embed.plnkr.co/VWicnA/

Comment: very concise solution. But this syntax is not very clear to me, especially `.at(0)` method?

Comment: Hey Thanks .. Yes Check this Docs out https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/forms/index/FormArray-class.html

On a form Array you have a Method to get  `at(index: number) : AbstractControl`

Answer (score 1):

Here is a way to access and patch a FormArray in Angular 2. I have modified your code to get this to work using your Plunk.

```
import { Inject, Component } from '@angular/core';
import { FormBuilder, FormArray }       from '@angular/forms';

@Component({
  moduleId: __moduleName,
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `<div><pre>{{ myForm.value | json }}</pre></div>`
})
export class AppComponent {

  public myForm: FormGroup;

  constructor(@Inject(FormBuilder) private _fb: FormBuilder) {

    this.myForm = this._fb.group({
      name: 'Cars',
      list:  this._fb.array([
        this.initCar(),
        this.initCar(),
        this.initCar()
      ]),
    });

    this.myForm.patchValue({name: 'Automobile'});

    /** Make changes here ***/
    // access the array from the form
    var items = this.myForm.get('list');

    // change the first item
    items.patchValue([{
      model: 'Fiesta'
    }]);

    // change the second item (notice the comma in front of the array)
    items.patchValue([,
    {
      model: 'TLX',
      automaker: 'Acura'
    }]);

    // change the third item (notice the 2 commas in front of the array)
    items.patchValue([,,
    {
      model: 'Accord',
      automaker: 'Honda'
    }]);

  };

  initCar() {
    return this._fb.group({
      automaker: 'Ford',
      model:     'Fusion'
    });
  }

}
```

Output before:

```
{
  "name": "Automobile",
  "list": [
    {
      "automaker": "Ford",
      "model": "Fusion"
    },
    {
      "automaker": "Ford",
      "model": "Fusion"
    },
    {
      "automaker": "Ford",
      "model": "Fusion"
    }
  ]
}
```

Output after:

```
{
  "name": "Automobile",
  "list": [
    {
      "automaker": "Ford",
      "model": "Fiesta"
    },
    {
      "automaker": "Acura",
      "model": "TLX"
    },
    {
      "automaker": "Honda",
      "model": "Accord"
    }
  ]
}
```

**EDIT:** A better solution:

```
// access the array from the form
var items = this.myForm.get('list');

const item1 = (items).at(0);
// change the first item
item1.patchValue({model: 'Fiesta'});

// change the second item
const item2 = (items).at(1);
item2.patchValue({
  model: 'TLX',
  automaker: 'Acura'
});

// change the third item
const item3 = (items).at(2);
item3.patchValue({
  model: 'Accord',
  automaker: 'Honda'
});
```

Comment: Hmm, but how I can get item by index. `list[9]` = [,,,,,,,,,] ?

Comment: Yeah, it isn't ideal. Accessing these via an index would be better. I tried that, but it was getting late, and I wanted to get this out. I may play with it more.