# how to set value in formArray

Tags: forms, angular

I have got a formgroup named input form, having an formarray of topics. I want to change the value of an inputfield using a dynamically created filtered list.

the filter function works fine:

```
filtertopic(idx: number) {
  const test = this.topics.value[idx].topic;
  if (test !== "") {
    this.onderdeel = "topics";
    this.queryselector = idx;
    this.filteredList = this.Topics.filter(function(el) {
      return el.toLowerCase().indexOf(test.toLowerCase()) >-1;
    }.bind(this));
     } else { this.filteredList = [];
    }
    }
```

but the function handleBlur to change the value in the input field does not work

```
handleBlur() {
    console.log(this.selectedIdx);
    if (this.selectedIdx > -1) {
      if (this.onderdeel =="topics") {
        this.topics.value[this.queryselector].topic.setValue(this.filteredList[this.selectedIdx]);
      } else {
        this.query = this.filteredList[this.selectedIdx];
      }
    }
    this.filteredList = [];
    this.selectedIdx = -1;
}
```

I think it has to do with the

> this.topics.value[this.queryselector].topic.setValue(this.filteredList[this.selectedIdx]);

to set the formcontrol value. Does anybody know the solution?

Comment: All is explained in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41645677/change-formbuilder-array-items-in-nested-forms

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
 this.yourdataobject.forEach(task => {
      this.formcontrolname.push(
        this.fb.group({
          name: [task.name, Validators.required]
        })
      );
    });
```